# Test if two curves have the same shape

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, splines, f-test

I have a gene expression measured for 5 humans (7 different layers each: L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, WM) and 4 chimpanzee  (7 different layers each: L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, WM). What I want to do is to compare gene expression profiles across the layers. More specifically I want to check if two profiles have the same shape (see the picture).
[image: The comparison of gene profiles]

I feel that there should be an easy way to do this. Something like:

1. Fit the smoothing spline for human profile
2. Fit the smoothing spline for chimp profile
3. Substract the two and compare it with `y ~ mean_human - mean_chimp` using F-test

But I'm not sure how to do this right.

For now I do it using permutations:

1. I substracted the average across the layers for each sample to eliminate the difference because of average level of expression
2. Fit the smoothing spline for human profile
3. Fit the smoothing spline for chimp profile
4. Fit the smoothing spline for (human + chimp) profile
5. Calculate residuals for each model ($RES_{H}$, $RES_{C}$, $RES_{HC}$) and F statistic
   $$
   F = \frac{RES_{HC} - RES_{H} - RES_{C}}{RES_{H} + RES_{C}}
   $$
6. Do permutations (n=1000) to find the distribution of F-statistic and calculate p-value

But it feels weird to compare the splines this way. The illustration of dataset table you can see here bellow

| Sample_id | layer | condition | expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| human1 | L1 | human | 10 |
| human1 | L2 | human | 5 |
| human1 | L3 | human | 6 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| human1 | WM | human | 7 |
| human2 | L1 | human | 11 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| human5 | WM | human | 8 |
| chimp1 | L1 | chimpanzee | 20 |
| chimp1 | L2 | chimpanzee | 15 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| chimp4 | WM | chimpanzee | 16 |

Comment: As `layer` looks discrete, you can smooth it. Otherwise, this would be relatively easy with the equivalent of an interaction term, just between a factor and a smooth.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Using an interaction term between a factor and a smooth (layers can be thought as continuous) really worked out well! I will add updates to share with everyone and make sure that I've done everything right in a few days

Comment: I should have said *can't* smooth a discrete variable, but if you can think of layer as being continuous as you drew it then a factor by smooth term, or a sz basis in mgcv will do what you show pictorially quite easily via a GAM.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to have some sort of similarity function / distance metric. For the shape, you may be able to use the [Earth Movers Distance (Wasserstein)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).